# How to iterate over records in Couchbase using either functions or operators

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am having two buckets in my couchbase cluster. I want to iterate all jsonDocuments present in bucket2 for each jsonDocument in bucket1 and I want to merge selected fields from bucket1 into bucket2 using some logic.

The following is the pseudo steps

```
for(JsonDocument inDoc: bucket1Docs) {
    for(JsonDocument outDoc: bucket2Docs) {
        JsonObject obj = outDoc.content();
        // After some arithmetic calculations
        obj.put(inDoc.content().get("key1"));
         bucket2.upsert(JsonDocument.create(key, obj));
    }
}
```

Note: bucket2 contains 100k records. I am also interested to perform this operation in paginated way.

I need a couchbase query string to perform the above operations.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this directly from N1QL, you can use this statement:

```
upsert into bucket2 (KEY original_id, VALUE original_doc) 
    select meta().id original_id, b original_doc from bucket1 b
```

If you want to do some more complicated merges in case the existing document already exists, check out the MERGE statement:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/merge.html

The OBJECT_CONCAT() function may also be useful if you want to combine values from two objects into one.
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html#object_concat

Comment: I am expecting to merge two buckets without keys and write it into bucket2